# Qemu KVM Passthrough - could not add USB device

Tags: linux, usb, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu

I try to run a windows vm on linux with qemu/kvm and pci-passthrough, but I get the following error when I start the vm:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice host:046d:c227: could not add USB device 'host:046d:c227'
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c227 Logitech, Inc. G15 Refresh Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c226 Logitech, Inc. G15 Refresh Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c223 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1384 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Startscript:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-m 16392 \
-cpu host,kvm=off \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=2 \
-vga none \
-usb -usbdevice host:046d:c227 -usbdevice host:046d:c226 \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars.fd \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
-drive file=/var/iso/win10.iso,id=isocd,format=raw,if=none -device scsi-cd,drive=isocd \
-drive file=/home/icehawk/images/windows10.img,id=disk,format=raw,if=none,cache=writeback -device scsi-hd,drive=disk \
-drive file=/var/iso/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso,id=virtiocd,if=none,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=virtiocd
```

I tried to pass through the whole bus or other various combinations, doesn't work either. Everytime, the first usb device is listed in the error message. I looked into this thread, but the answers doesn't help me: [USB passthrough for QEMU gets error "qemu: could not add USB device"](https://superuser.com/questions/1005571/usb-passthrough-for-qemu-gets-error-qemu-could-not-add-usb-device)

I use the newest qemu version 2.7.9 (aka 2.8 rc0)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Found a solution: Had to compile qemu with --enable-libusb and --enable-usb-redir

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. This is [the right thing to do](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found a solution**: Had to compile qemu with `--enable-libusb` and `--enable-usb-redir`