# QEMU USB passthrough -device usb-host: drive exists

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, usb-2

I am using Qemu, running on an Arch Host to use a Windows VM, and I need to passthrough the webcam. It is an integrated webcam using USB>=2.

`lsusb` yields for this device
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia`

Here is the script I am using (`win-start.sh`):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
     -m 8G \
     -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp cores=4 \
     -vga virtio -display sdl,gl=on \
     -drive file=win,format=raw \
     -device nec-usb-xhci\
     -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=2\
     2>&1 win.log
```

But this stops with:
`qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=2: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists`
And I cannot find where the error is. The VM boots without a problem when I remove the 2 `-device` lines.

This script is based on what I could find there :
https://superuser.com/a/1077369/1021190

And the folder is setup as such:

```
ls -lh win*
-rw-r--r-- 1 soulthym users 128G Apr 13 19:34 win
-rw-r--r-- 1 soulthym users 4.4G Apr 11 20:28 win.iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 soulthym users    0 Apr 13 18:57 win.log
-rwxr-xr-x 2 soulthym users  297 Apr 13 19:57 win-start.sh
```

Comment: Did you forget to add a space before the '\' in the bash command?

Comment: @travisjayday is it important? I thought it didn't matter

Comment: Hmm nvm, probably not. My bad. If you hadn't had the tabs on the next lines it would have made a difference. I was thinking the arguments were being passed wrong (without spaces inbetween)